# Is it possible to use data-sly-test and data-sly-list togheter?

Tags: aem, sling, sightly

I have a list that contains 10 items.

I need to show only the items having a certain codeModel

```
<div data-sly-use.promotions= "com.example.myCodeModel">
<div data-sly-list.promo="${promotions.promotions}">
<article data-sly-test="${inheritedPageProperties['codeModel']  == promo.attributes['Model'].codeModel}">
.....
</article>
</div>
</div>
```

It doesn't work (no `<article>` is displayed) but if I write the values of ${inheritedPageProperties['codeModel']} and ${promo.attributes['Model'].codeModel} I see that they are the same. 
I don't understand why the 'equals' condition fails.

Any suggestions?

Comment: (no [code]<article>[code] is displayed)

Answer (score 0):

I think that inheritedPageProperties['codeModel'] returns a JavaScript String while the other method returns a Java String, not sure 100% since I don't have a 6.XX instance running right now, maybe you should move your check in the Java class and avoid doing this operation in the view and keep it in the controller, you have access to getInheritedPageProperties() if you are extending WCMUse.

I think this is one of the gotchas of Rhino...to be confirmed...

Comment: Solved
<article data-sly-test="data-sly-test="${promo.attributes['Model'].modelCode == pageProperties.modelCode}"> ....
</article>